# While footer home page click event android keyboard only fire in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using android phonegap cordova1.8.0 and jquery1.7.1.  My phonegap application having header and footer with text-field and drop down contents. In header, having one back button it should navigate to home page, footer having one home button its also navigate to home page. In content view, it has 4 text-field, and 2 drop-downs. while selecting home button in footer page, the back-side content's text-field only firing and android keyboard only open, footer home button is not firing, its same in header back- button click event also.

here my screen shots  [image]

any one can help me?

Comment: are you dealing with any sort of css with your application?

Comment: i maintain different css for different type of android device resolution

Comment: try to set higher gravity for your footer menu bar.

Comment: can u please explain clearly?

Comment: post some code how you have declared your footer menu?

Comment: <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" 
            style="bottom: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;display:none;" id="frstfooter">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-tab-search" onclick="loadSearch();"></a> 
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-tab-home" onclick="location.href='#home';"></a>  
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-tab-settings" onclick="location.href='#settings';"></a> 
                         
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the placement of your controls.

Try to set this css property for your footer div :

```
 z-index: 1000;
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to set your details view area with subtract height of the footer menu.

Comment: @user if my given solution helps you somehow to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user okay np. I will let you know If I will get something relevant with your problem.